# Add mail button to list field when date is in future

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Using SharePoint online in office 365.

According to the Microsoft docs ["Add an action button to a field"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#add-an-action-button-to-a-field-advanced) it is possible to render a Mail `IconName` including `quickActions` element to open email when clicked. Now I do not want to use the email address of a `Persons` column, but instead I would like to use the formatting JSON on a `text` column (e.g. `Title`) with the action directing to a standard mail address `xx@yy.com`:

In the list settings of the `Title` column with the JSON formatter, I place the following JSON code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "style": {
                    "text-decoration": "none"
                },
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:xx@yy.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But nothing happens, so my first question is what is currently going wrong?

Then I would preferably only render this Mail icon and apply this quickAction, when the given date of another column, let's say `Final date` is still in the future. So preferably combine it with the example in the Microsoft docs ["Formatting an item when a date column is before or after today's date"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#formatting-an-item-when-a-date-column-is-before-or-after-todays-date-advanced):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Final Date] <= @now, '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON code like below for your requirements:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "display": "=if([$FinalDate] > @now, 'block', 'none')"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": "mailto:xx@yy.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I noticed I had my column named `Final Date`, but when referring to that column you need to remove the space inbetween --> `[$FinalDate]`

Comment: Yes, you have to use internal name of column.